# 2008 Sonata starter signal connector replacement

Tags: hyundai, starter, sonata, connector

When working on a starter I've found that signal connector locking tab was broken. I would like to find a replacement, de-pin the broken connector and insert pins into the new one, avoiding pig tails and splices.

What is the type of two-pin connector I need, is it industry standard, or Hyundai-specific, and how would I generally find this information reliably? Would it appear in the parts diagram of the harness, for instance?

[image: photo of the connector]

Comment: If you are trying to replace that female connector in the snapshot, most likely difficult to buy alone from Hyundai. You can try searching to see if its a universal connector used in other vehicles or find one from salvage yards. This may not have to be replaced if the female lug within it is loose when connected to its male spade lug. Carefully bending the two U shaped parts closer to meet the metal should close the gap to create a tight fit onto the male spade lug without needing the plastic connector locked onto its female connector.

Comment: @FDryer, I need the whole plastic bit in the image replaced. The corresponding end is on the starter solenoid itself. I don't trust just the tight fit there, because it's a mission critical component, and hard to get to if it comes off (I have to take battery, air supply, and radiator fan and shroud just to access the starter). I don't mind getting the aftermarket one, but I need to know what to look for.

Comment: Yes, very understandable but my suggestion to create more bite from the female connector will aid in maintaining a secure electrical connection. Another alternative to securing this single wire is to tie a length of nylon cord to each end of the connections or use an appropriately sized piece of shrink tubing to fit over the two plastic connections then heat shrink it to form a lock, preventing the two connections from coming apart. There are many ways to address this if you cannot find an exact replacement part. There should be enough wires to prevent inadvertent physical strain.